# result array of 'post_name' Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, slug

when I try to run this array it doesn't give me the exact results of the 4 slugs I want to get, but many more results come out:

```
$slugArray = array(

    'post_type' =>  'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_name__in' => array( 'permalink1', 'permalink2', 'permalink3', 'permalink4' ),

);



 // Get all posts
$query = new WP_Query($slugArray);

$posts = $query->get_posts();
```

below I paste the script continuum to modify these slugs that I should insert in the array.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {


    if($post) {


                    
    //if $post->post_name, (preg_match("/^([0-9]+)\-(.*)/", $match))
        if(preg_match("/^([0-9]+)\-(.*)/", $post->post_name, $match))
    $new_slug = (intval($match[1])+1) . "-" . $match[2];
        else
            $new_slug = "1-" . $post->post_name;

    // Prepare arguments
    $args = array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,          
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_name' => $new_slug,
    );
    // Update post
    //wp_update_post( $args );
        var_dump ($args);
}
}

?>
```

so i should just get:

```
array(3) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["post_name__in"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(20) "permalink1" [1]=> string(30) "permalink2" [2]=> string(12) "permalink3" [3]=> string(22) "permalink4" }
```

but instead I get another 1000 different post_name results

Comment: I'm having trouble in understanding what you're trying to do, If you could give more context, explain what you're trying to do in more details, what is your post structure looks like ... Keep in mind we are not next to you

Comment: this is a code to change the permalinks of the slugs i get in post_name__in array, the problem is that I don't just get these 4 slugs when I try to run "var_dump", but i get these 4 slugs + 1000 more slugs, i hope i made it clearer :)